# Sharepoint Central Admin UI Source location

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm sure i have seen a place on the disk where i could browse the aspx-files for the sharepoint central administration so i could build the same look and feel for my own pages.

For example i would like to see the source for

```
http://localhost:26538/_admin/Server.aspx
```

I know "View Source" in the browser is possible, but i have seen them on disk somewhere. Anyone else have been using this? Where do you locate them?

Thanks in advance.

/Lyck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are asking for is:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN

It is also know as `14 hive`.

Answer (score 0):

For any of the /_[anything]/ directories for SharePoint, they all lead back to the same place for the same name. I think there are 4 or 5 of them (_layouts, _admin, _trust, _controltemplates).

What I do to simply it is just open IIS, view the _[anything] directory and click "Explore" in the top right area of IIS. Like I said, all SharePoint websites share the exact same source directory for these virtual directories.